# Aggregating a single column with dplyr with all other columns as conditions

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe

```
 df<-data.frame(V1=c("F","D","R","F","A"),V2=c("G","B","D","G","F"),F3=c(11,0,13,14,16),V4=c("G","B","O","G","F"),V5=c("G","B","D","G","F"))
 df
  V1   V2 F3 V4 V5
1  F    G 11  G  G
2  D    B  0  B  B
3  R    D 13  O  D
4  F    G 14  G  G
5  A    F 16  F  F
```

I want to agragate V3 based on all other columns
When I have few columns I use

```
library(plyr)
 df1 <- ddply(D,~V1+V2+V4+V5,summarise,V3=sum(V3))
```

but what if I have data frame with unknown number of  Vs , or with different names with no patterns?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe: `aggregate(F3 ~ ., df, sum)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `dplyr` you can use different ways to group data -

1. Group columns that start with `'V'`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(across(starts_with('V'))) %>%
  summarise(F3 = sum(F3), .groups = 'drop')
```

2. Group all the character columns

```
df %>%
  group_by(across(where(is.character))) %>%
  summarise(F3 = sum(F3), .groups = 'drop')
```

3. Group columns 1, 2 and 4, 5

```
df %>%
  group_by(across(c(1:2, 4:5))) %>%
  summarise(F3 = sum(F3), .groups = 'drop')
```

4. Group everything except `F3`

```
df %>%
  group_by(across(-F3)) %>%
  summarise(F3 = sum(F3), .groups = 'drop')
```

5. Group everything except 3rd column.

```
df %>%
  group_by(across(-3)) %>%
  summarise(F3 = sum(F3), .groups = 'drop')
```

All of them return the same output.

```
#  V1    V2    V4    V5       F3
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#1 A     F     F     F        16
#2 D     B     B     B         0
#3 F     G     G     G        25
#4 R     D     O     D        13
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `tidyverse` way:

1. With `chop` build blocks on `F3`
2. Use `unnest_wider` to unnest `F3`
3. build `rowSums` of specific cols `F3_1` `F3_2`

```
libraryr(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  chop(F3) %>% 
  unnest_wider(F3, names_sep = "_" ) %>% 
  mutate(F3 = rowSums(.[c("F3_1","F3_2")], na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  select(-c(F3_1, F3_2))
```

```
  V1    V2    V4    V5       F3
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 F     G     G     G        25
2 D     B     B     B         0
3 R     D     O     D        13
4 A     F     F     F        16
```